# Integration Testing RabbitMQ listner - Intermittently failing because the message takes time to be queued

Tags: spring-rabbit, integration-testing

I have written an integration test for the following flow using RabbitMock (found it on github and it seems really cool):

Message gets added to Incoming-message-queue --> incoming message listner picks up the message --> processes it --> puts a new outgoing message to the new queue Outgoing-message-queue --> (only for tests) wrote a listner for this outgoing queue in src/test/resources.

Everything is working (with one important glitch - intermittent timeout) and I am doing asserts as shown below:

```
List<OutgoingData> receivedMessages = new ArrayList<>();
            assertTimeoutPreemptively(ofMillis(15000L), () -> {
                    while (receivedMessages.isEmpty()) {
                        OutgoingData data = 
receiver.getOutgoingData();
                        if(data != null){
                            receivedMessages.add(data);
                        }

                    }
                }
            );

            assertThat(receivedMessages.get(0)).isNotNull();

 assertThat
(receivedMessages.get(0).getRecipient())
.isEqualTo("enabled@localhost");
```

The timeout in this test is real issue I am facing.

1. Because of the timeout, the tests are getting slow.
2. If I remove the timeout, tests are getting stuck in Jenkins and need to be killed forcefully.
3. At times, this 15000 milliseconds timeout is also not enough and the tests fail.

I was wondering if there is a better way to deal with such a situation in the integration test.

Looking forward to your inputs.

Thanks a lot,
Banyanbat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I gave it a little more thought and talked to one of my team members about this, it clicked my mind that java 8 futures can be effectively used here.

I implemented it as follows and it worked like a charm.

```
@Test
public void basic_consume_case()
        InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    IncomingData incomingData = new IncomingData();
    incomingData.setRecipient("enabled@localhost");
    incomingData.setSender("unblocked@localhost");
    incomingData.setStoreKey("123");
    incomingData.setSubject("Hello");
    incomingData.setText("Hello from Test 1");
    try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new 
   AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            ConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class)) {

        sendMessage(incomingData);

        Future<OutgoingData> receivedMessageFuture = pollOutgoingQueueForData();

        OutgoingData receivedMessage = receivedMessageFuture.get();

        assertThat(receivedMessage).isNotNull();
        assertThat(receivedMessage.getRecipient()).isEqualTo("enabled@localhost");
        assertThat(receivedMessage.getContent())
        ...

    }
}
private void sendMessage(IncomingData incomingData) {
    try {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("incoming-data-queue", incomingData, m -> {
            m.getMessageProperties().setContentType("application/json");
            return m;
        });

    } finally {
    }
}

private Future<OutgoingData> pollOutgoingQueueForData() throws InterruptedException {

    return executor.submit(() -> {
        OutgoingData receivedMessage = null;
        while (receivedMessage == null) {
            receivedMessage = (OutgoingData) 
rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert("outgoing-queue");
        }
        return receivedMessage;
    });

}
```